# Se eu declarar uma variável global para minha página, ela fica acessível apenas nesta sessão?

Tags: c#, asp.net, variáveis, session, webforms

Olá,

Estou com uma dúvida. Se eu declarar variáveis globais para página, elas são exclusivas para esta sessão ou elas pode ser alteradas em outras sessões?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tive problemas em outros sistemas que desenvolvi com o uso de propriedades criadas em class.cs que ficavam disponíveis em todas as sessões e por isso uma sessão tinha seus dados alterados por outra sessão sendo executada por outro usuário.

Comment: Quando assim use [variáveis de Sessão](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.session?view=netframework-4.8). ["Uma visão globla sobre estados de sessão"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178581(v=vs.100))

Answer (score 0):

Não existe nada de global no seu código, apenas a `string id` que sempre será inicializada com o valor `"rd1"` toda a vez que a classe `espelho_de_vendas` for isntanciada, ela receberá esse valor, que poderá ser manipulado posteriormente, como por exemplo, no evento do `Page_Load` e só terá efeito para quem fez a requisição à página.